# Git checking out remote branch without specifying `origin/`

Tags: git

Since git version 1.6.6 there is a very handy abbreviation for checking out a remote branch. You can write:

`git checkout test`

instead of

`git checkout -b test origin/test`

This behavior has caused my some trouble though in the past together with `git-completion` in terminal. First the completion always lists all of the remote branches as well, and second I already accidentally checked out a remote branch that was named similarly to the local branch I actually wanted.

So my question is, can one force git to not accept the above abbreviation (and in turn git-completion/bash-completion as well)?

Comment: I wonder if you can have it a least warn first.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss For a reversible process, especially a non-destructive one, it's better to do what the user asked and let them undo it later. The alternative is to constantly second guess them. That said, I've been using Git for years and never knew about this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent git-completion from considering remote branches when tab-completing `git checkout [TAB]`, I finally modified the `git-completion.bash` as follows:

- search for `_git-checkout()`
- replace `...__git_refs...` in this function with `...__git_head...`

To further retain the functionality to auto-complete remote branches (and only remote branches to origin), I did the following

- `git config --global alias.rco checkout`
- copy the original `_git-checkout()` as `_git-rco()`
- replace `$(__git_refs '' $track)` with `$(__git_refs 'origin' $track)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a local branch named like a remote (from the current HEAD position) do a `git checkout --no-track -b <branchName>` it should force your branch not to be a tracking branch. If you do a `git branch -vv` it will list all your branches and for those that are tracking, will show who they track.